# Psychopy no response keyboard

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm doing an experimentation where the participant needs to pressed the keyboard. I would like to know if the participant :

1) pressed the good key

2) wrong key

3) no response

I have this line of code :

```
if key_resp_4.keys == response:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 1)
elif key_resp_4.keys == 'None':
    thisExp.addData('correct', -1)
else:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
```

I tried to change 'None' for '', None, but I always get a 0 in my correct column even if I did not pressed any key.

Thanks

Comment: What does `print(repr(key_resp_4.keys))` show in that situation?

Comment: Hum.. I dont understand. I work in the builder. I wrote this piece of code in a code component

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

That's the good code, if it can help someone :

```
if key_resp_4.keys == response:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 1)
elif key_resp_4.keys == [] :
    thisExp.addData('correct', -1)
else:
    thisExp.addData('correct', 0)
```